# How to work two different type submit button in same form in php?

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<input type= "submit" value="load" name="load" onclick="form.action='inputmarks.php?epr=save'"><input type="submit" value="submit" name='submit' id="submit" onclick="form.action='inputmarks.php?epr=go'">

<?php if(isset($_GET['epr']))
$epr=$_GET['epr'];
if($epr = 'save')
{echo "<p><input name='newcourseID' value='$courseID'>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input name='newsessionID' value='$sessionID'>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input name='newtermID' value='$termID'>";echo "ok1";}?>
<?php
if($epr = 'go')
{$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databaseName);
for ($y = 0; $y < $student; $y++) {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++){
        $a=$studentID[$y];
        $b=$marksID[$x];
$sql9 =" INSERT INTO tbl_course_marks_result(CourseID,SessionID,TermID,StudentID,MarksID) VALUES ('$courseID2','$sessionID2','$termID2','$a','$b') ";
$result9= mysqli_query($connect,$sql9);
echo "submit";
}
}
}
```

my problem in this code is; when I click on load button it also do the work of submit button, and when I click on submit button it also do the work of load button. but I want just one specified function for each of the buttons.

Comment: Your code is failing on a few levels here.

Comment: where's the actual problem. could you please elaborate?